# Access Primary Key Basic Understanding

Tags: ms-access-2007, primary-key

This is a bit of a gneral question, but I can't seem to find an explicit answer.

Let's say I have an import table, with a primary key added by Access. Then another table that I use to cleanup, etc. then connect to Excel.

If I delete a record from my first table (let's say, primary key 123). And then I append a bunch of records to it, will primary key 123 be used, or will Access "know" that that key was used previously and subsequently deleted? Will it fill a record using that key because it's available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a primary key added by Access

This is always an AutoNumber column.

It will **not** re-use a previously deleted ID.

Exception: if you delete the last appended record(s), and then compact&repair the database, the AutoNumber "seed" will be reset to (current maximum ID) + 1.

But gaps in the IDs will never be filled.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton Andre451.